# Rails 4.1 undefined method `usual_start_time' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form which creates the default time of 6.45pm. When a  new form is created

_form.html.erb

```
 = f.input :started_at, as: :string, class: 'form-control', input_html: { value: l(@happening.started_at, format: :date_time_picker), class: 'date_time_picker' }, label: "Start at"
```

but instead of showing 1845 in my happenings controller  i want to replace it with the usual_start_time field in my areas table

scheme.rb

```
create_table "areas", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "deprecated__default_postcode", limit: 255
    t.integer "number_of_runners_needed",                 default: 100,     null: false
    t.string  "referral_partners_logo_image"
    t.integer "address_id"
    **t.string  "usual_start_time",                         default: "18:45"**
  end
```

I have tried using

```
time = DateTime.strptime((Date.today + 1.day).to_s + ' ' + **"#{@area.usual_start_time}"**, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

but it gives me undefined method `usual_start_time' for nil:NilClass

also tried

```
time = DateTime.strptime((Date.today + 1.day).to_s + ' ' + **"#{@area.happenings.usual_start_time}"**, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

happenings_controller.rb (want to replace "18.45"

```
  def new
    @type = params[:type].underscore
    time = DateTime.strptime((Date.today + 1.day).to_s + ' ' + **"18:45"**, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    @happening = Happening.new(started_at: time)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that `@area` isn't initialized in your controller.

`@area` isn't an instance of `Area` class in your view, it's `nil`, and no `usual_start_time` is defined for `nil`.

Comment: so could i just replace the last line (at)happening = Happening.new(started_at: time) with (at)Area.happening = Happening.new(started_at: time)

Comment: Possibly. We don't see the relationship of Area and Happening in your question.

Comment: thanks got it working by initializing the @area instance variable

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your @area instance variable isn't set anywhere and is returning nil.

Are you wanting to change the attribute value of the started_at on the Happening model?  If so, you could do this in the Happening#create method, and just do @happening.started_at = 18:45

Comment: I want users to see 18:45 by default. When they create a new form. It does work with "645" but wanting to replace with the string "usual_start_time" in my areas table (which is 1845!)